# Проверка логина preg_match

Tags: php

Требуется регулярное выражение проверки по логину.

Допускается использовать только латинские буквы, цифры, "-", "_" (черту и подчеркивание). Минимальное количество лат. букв - 4, максимальное количество цифр - 4, подчеркиваний и черточек - 4.

Моя изначальная строка:

```
if( preg_match( "/[\||\'|\<|\>|\[|\]|\"|\!|\?|\$|\@|\#|\/|\\\|\&\~\*\{\+]/", $name ) )
  $stop .= $lang['reg_err_4'];
```

Как можно ее поправить, чтобы соблюсти все условия?

Comment: А разве можно определить в регулярке максимальное количество, если они не подряд? Или имелось в виду как раз таки подряд идущие цифры и знаки? логин `ya12---misha--224potapov---666` валиден или нет?

Comment: теоретически можно выбрать 4 и заглянуть вперед, что там нет такого знака. Но выраженьице будет такое, что комп полчаса с ним разбираться будет. Гораздо правильнее отобрать на валидные символы, а количество каждой группы посчитать функциями для работы со строками

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы можете дополнительно ввести ограничение на количество символов, например, от 6 до 12

```
/([A-Za-z\d\-_]){6,12}/
```

чтобы нельзя было два подчеркивания подряд

```
^([A-Za-z\d\-]|_(?!_)){6,12}$
```

чтобы нельзя было два подчеркивания или минуса  подряд

```
^([A-Za-z\d]|_(?!_)|\-(?!\-)){6,12}$
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Comment: да не сильно есть за что - совсем все просто :)

Comment: Можете еще тогда немного помочь, если Вас не затруднит?

Comment: Можете к этому выражению ? "/([A-Za-z\d\-_])/" Добавить еще следующее: чтоб подчеркивания нельзя было соединять. Ну то есть логин к примеру Fren__lion уже был бы не правильным, а Fren_L_i_oN правильным.

Comment: я обновил ответ. и, кстати, хороший стиль - принять ответ, если он правильный, нажав на галку слева от ответа. А когда рейтинг у вас подрастет, еще и нажать стрелочку вверх :)

Comment: Не только подчеркивания, черточки тоже. Можете пожалуйста обновить? )

Comment: Кстати, то выражение что вы первое написали. Я не пойму, я все равно могу регистрировать русский ник. Не могли бы вы мне по скайпу помочь немного ? такой же как и ник логин в скайпе. Был бы Вам очень признателен.

Comment: обновил имя http://prntscr.com/aymuku